# CSS - MULTIPLE DIV

Tags: html, css

How would I link css to sp-copyright

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="sp-footer1" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="sp-column ">
        <span class="sp-copyright">
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you're trying to do: by `link css to ..` do you mean that you want to select that `span` in order to style it, or something else?

Comment: yes i want to link css to style span but have other span I dont want styled

Comment: as well as I want to link css to style sp-column

Comment: but I cant seem to get i to work using }
.sp-column {
 margin-top: 10%;

}

Comment: See Yonatan's answer below, it should help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To style classes you use a "." before the class name.
To style id's you'd use a "#" before the id name.

Note that "margin-top" won't work on inline elements (like span is).
You can use a div instead, which is a "block" element, and then add margin to that.

Or, instead, make the span a block element.

```
<style>
 .sp-copyright {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }
 #example {
  border: 1px solid blue; 
 }
</style>
```